# Scrapy to crawl LD JSON data

Tags: python, scrapy

I have done some research but can't seem to find any information on if it is possible to crawl something like JSON Schema data from a URL. An example i just found as i was looking at the product anyway would be:

https://www.reevoo.com/p/panasonic-nn-e271wmbpq

```
    <script class="microdata-snippet" type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Product",
  "name": "PANASONIC NN-E271WMBPQ",
  "image": "https://images.reevoo.com/products/3530/3530797/550x550.jpg?fingerprint=73ed91807dac7eb8f899757a348c735446d0a1fe&gravity=Center"


    ,"category": {
      "@type": "Thing",
      "name": "Microwave",
      "url": "https://www.reevoo.com/browse/product_type/microwaves"
    }



    ,"description": "Auto weight programs will automatically calculate the cooking time, once the weight has been entered. Acrylic lining makes cleaning easy, simply wipe after use. Child lock provides extra security to prevent little fingers interfering with the programming of the oven. \nAll our compact microwave ovens are packed with flexible features to make everyday cooking simple. Auto weight programs will automatically calculate the cooking time, once the weight has been entered. Acrylic lining makes cleaning easy, simply wipe after use. Child lock provides extra security to prevent little fingers interfering with the programming of the oven."



    ,"aggregateRating": {
      "@type": "AggregateRating",
      "ratingValue": "8.7",
      "ratingCount": 636,
      "worstRating": "1",
      "bestRating": "10"
    }

}
</script>
```

So would it be possible to extract say the rating data?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4):

```
import json
```

And next in your code:

```
microdata_content = response.xpath('//script[@type="application/ld+json"]/text()').extract_first()
microdata = json.loads(microdata_content)

ratingValue = microdata["aggregateRating"]["ratingValue"]
```